# Child Activity ListView updates Parent Activity's ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, android-activity

I have a problem where the Child Activity's list view updates the content of the Parent Activity's List View.

Basically, in my Parent Activity (DetailActivity) I have a List View called lvContacts which I populate with the following code:

```
ListView lvDetail = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvContacts);
SingleLineAdapter adapter = new SingleLineAdapter(this, Items);
lvDetail.setAdapter(adapter);
lvDetail.setSelector(R.drawable.generic_selector);
```

Where Items is an ArrayList of GenericDataObject:

```
public class GenericDataObject implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 7661717999129942666L;
private String Id;
private String Description;
private String RawData;

// getters and setters snipped for smaller code
}
```

The SingleLineAdapter looks like this:

```
public class SingleLineAdapter extends CustomListAdapter implements Filterable {
private static ArrayList<GenericDataObject> ObjectArray;
private static ArrayList<GenericDataObject> OriginalArray;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private String SearchedText = "";
private Context OriginatingContext;

public SingleLineAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<GenericDataObject> Objects) {
    OriginatingContext = context;
    ObjectArray = Objects;
    OriginalArray = Objects;
    layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    if (Objects != null)
        Collections.sort(Objects, ObjectComparator);
}

private Comparator<GenericDataObject> ObjectComparator = new Comparator<GenericDataObject>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(GenericDataObject object1,
            GenericDataObject object2) {
        return object1.getDescription().compareTo(object2.getDescription());
    }
};

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return ObjectArray.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return ObjectArray.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_generic, null);
           holder = new ViewHolder();
           holder.lblTitle = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblTitle);

           convertView.setTag(holder);
          } else {
           holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.lblTitle.setText(ObjectArray.get(position).getDescription(), TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE);

    if (!SearchedText.equals("")) {
        Spannable wordToSpan = (Spannable)holder.lblTitle.getText();
        String[] comps;
        if (SearchedText.startsWith("\""))
            comps = new String[] { SearchedText.substring(1, SearchedText.length() - 1) };
        else
            comps = SearchedText.split(" ");

        String name = holder.lblTitle.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
        for(int i = 0; i < comps.length; i++) {
            int Start = name.indexOf(comps[i]);
            while (Start > -1) {
                int End = Start + comps[i].length();
                wordToSpan.setSpan(new BackgroundColorSpan(0xFFFF9900), Start, End, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
                Start = name.indexOf(comps[i], End);
            }
        }
    }
    setFont(holder.lblTitle);

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView lblTitle;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            SearchedText = constraint.toString();
            final FilterResults result = new FilterResults();

            final ArrayList<GenericDataObject> custs = new ArrayList<GenericDataObject>();
            if(constraint != null) {
                String[] searches;
                if (constraint.toString().startsWith("\"") && constraint.toString().endsWith("\""))
                    searches = new String[] { SearchedText.substring(1, SearchedText.length() - 1) };
                else
                    searches = constraint.toString().split(" ");
                for(int i = 0; i < OriginalArray.size(); i++) {
                    String customerName = OriginalArray.get(i).getDescription().toLowerCase();

                    boolean bNotFound = false;
                    for(int j = 0; j < searches.length && bNotFound == false; j++) {
                        String searchFor = searches[j];
                        if (!customerName.contains(searchFor))
                            bNotFound = true;
                    }

                    if (!bNotFound)
                    {
                        custs.add(OriginalArray.get(i));
                    }
                }
                result.values = custs;
            }
            return result;
        }

        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint,
                FilterResults results) {
            ObjectArray = (ArrayList<GenericDataObject>)results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}
}
```

The OnItemClick for lvContacts queries for data on a web service then shows a new Activity:

```
Intent detail = new Intent(DetailActivity.this, ContactDetailActivity.class);
detail.putExtra("ListOfDetails", RowsFromService);
startActivity(detail);
```

The RowsFromService is an ArrayList of GenericDataObject as well.

In the ContactDetailActivity, I have a ListView called lvContactDetail. I populate this by:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ArrayList<GenericDataObject> DetailRows = (ArrayList<GenericDataObject>)getIntent().getExtras().getSerializable("ListOfDetails");
    ListView lvContactDetail = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvContactDetail);
    SingleLineAdapter detailAdapter = new SingleLineAdapter(this, DetailRows);
    lvContactDetail.setAdapter(detailAdapter);
    lvContactDetail.setSelector(R.drawable.generic_selector);
}
```

Everything up to this point works perfectly, but if I go back to the DetailActivity (Parent Activity) using the back button or even activity.finish() on a button, the original list (lvContacts) is now populated with the results of lvContactDetail.

This only happens with two lists in my app, all the rest are working 100% correctly.

Is there any special precautions to take note of when loading lists from other lists? It's worth noting that the main activity in my app sets flags for CLEAR_TOP and REORDER_TO_FRONT...

Strange enough: Even if I comment out the setAdapter line in the child activity, the parent activity is STILL being updated with the other activity's data. Can this be related to creating a new instance of SingleLineAdapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I'm the only person who actually experiences this problem, so what I've done is to just "reload" the UI portion of the parent activity in onCreate. (Keeping booleans to indicate if the data was loaded or not)